# Android Placepicker 2019

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

The [Android Placepicker is deprecated since last month](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/placepicker). How do i get or build a simple lat/long coordinates (place-)picker with the "new" Google Maps Platform (API)?

Comment: wont this help ? https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration#compat

Comment: Read the migration guide : https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration

Comment: Migration guide says "The Place Picker is only supported in the compatibility library, NOT in the new client library". And I write a new app, so i think i can not use the "old API" anymore.

Comment: my current workaround: Using another map-sdk: https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/location-picker/