# How to implement google map place picker in android after it has been deprecated

Tags: android, google-maps, google-place-picker

i want to use google map place picker in my android app but the Place Picker is deprecated and is not included in the new Places SDK. Please tell me how to implement the latest SDK in my android app

```
        new LatLng(47.64299816, -122.14351988));
PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
builder.setLatLngBounds(latLngBounds);

try {
    startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), PLACE_PICKER_REQ_CODE);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.getStackTrace().toString());
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Placepicker 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57414445/android-placepicker-2019)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the alternative.

> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.1.0'

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.google_maps_key));

    PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(this);

    mAutocompleteSupportFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.placeAutocompletefragment); // Fragment is declared in layout file 

    mAutocompleteSupportFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.LAT_LNG));

    mAutocompleteSupportFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(@NonNull Place place) {

            Log.d("PlaceAddress", "onPlaceSelected: " + place.getLatLng());

            LatLng queriedLocation = place.getLatLng();
            Log.v("Latitude is", "" + queriedLocation.latitude);
            Log.v("Longitude is", "" + queriedLocation.longitude);

            mLat = queriedLocation.latitude;
            mLng = queriedLocation.longitude;


        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull Status status) {

        }
    });
```

here you will get the latlng of selected place.